# Suffix removal not working in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

In my shell script I want to read *csv* file line by line, and remove prefix and suffix from one of the column.

here is a sample *input.csv*:

```
192.168.0.1, user1, "2zG7CBKp5d4z"
192.168.0.2, user2, "9vy6J,M2A3b6"
192.168.0.3, user3, "V5q,8mvz#$ac"
```

here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="$1"

while IFS="," read f1 f2 f3
do
        f3="${f3#\"}"
        f3="${f3%\"}"
        echo "$f1" "$f2" "$f3"

done <"$filename"
```

In the script with `while` I want to `ssh` to host (`$f1`) with user (`$f2`) and password (`$f3`), but have to remove the double-quote from `f3`. The `ssh` part will be implemented later. The prefix removal works as expected, but the suffix does NOT.
Anybody can tell me why ?

Comment: When I tried this (with a here-doc instead of separate file), it's the prefix removal that fails, since the third field begins with a space before `"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the trailing `"` works for me. I suspect that your lines, and therefore `f3`, do not end with `"` but with `\r` – the first part of a windows line break (`\r\n`), opposed to unix line breaks (`\n`).

Convert your file using `dos2unix original` or `tr -d \\r < original > converted`.

By the way, the last field is only read correctly because it is the last. Usually `read` would interpret the comma inside the last field as the beginning of a new field – `read` does not give special meaning to the quotes. However, `read` will read all remaining fields into the last variable given, in this case `f3`.

Comment: Ohhh yes... the line break was the problem. Changing it from \r\n to unix line breaks \n solve the problem.

Not required to ignore \r

Answer (score 0):

If the last field length is constant, `cut` efficiently gets rid of the quotes:

```
rev input.csv | cut -c2-13,15- | rev
```

If *all* the field lengths are constant, there's no need for `rev`:

```
cut -c-20,22-33 input.csv
```

Comment: Unlike the OP code, this answer doesn't change "," to " " , but if the first and last fields are fixed lengths, then `cut` could manage that as well using the same method.